# Cant add order to basket. when i click add to basket returns null

Tags: php, laravel

*function*

```
    public function basketAdd($productId){
    $orderId = session('orderId');
    if(is_null($orderId)){
        $order_id = Order::create()->id;
        session(['orderId'=>$orderId]);
    }
    dump($orderId);
}
```

*Here my code of html main page and card of orders but this cards cant be added to basket*

```
**Main page**
    <div class="container">
        <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>Все товары</h1>

            <div class="row">
                <h2>Количество товара на странице {{$product->count()}}</h2>
                @foreach($product as $pro)
                @include('card', compact('pro'))
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: '''<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{$pro->title}}</h3>
            <p>{{$pro->price}} dollar</p>
            <p>
                <form action="{{ route('basket-add', $pro ) }}" method="POST">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">В Корзину</button>
                @csrf

                </form>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>'' MY code of card

Comment: pleae, add this comment as part of your question

Comment: You are not passing ID in submission.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing productID in submission.
Debug your frontend query whether it is not sending null values.